# Считывание с консоли в сервлете

Tags: java, servlet

Использую bufferedreader в сервлете, по идее он должен ждать когда я напишу в консоли что, но он сразу же выдает null, и отвечает

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String strLine = in.readLine();

StrLine выдает null, что надо сделать чтобы считать с консоли?

Answer (score 1):

Так просто Вы это не сделаете. Контейнер сервлетов, скорее всего у Вас Tomcat, не имеет своего stdin-потока. То, что в Вашем понимании консоль в IDE - это перехват stdout-вывода Tomcat, и в него можно только писать. А вот чтобы можно было с клавиатуры сервлету что-то передать, как вариант можно написать консольное приложение и к нему по RMI обращаться